# problem with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i'm using wordpress, i have a page that i can access like this
http://mywebsite/category/page title/ i used Wordpress Permalinks to accomplish that, but i have a plugin inside my page so the page will be something like this http://mywebsite/category/page title/?var1=x&var2=y
i want to create a .htaccess file that will make my url http://mywebsite/category/page title/x/y and i will edit my plugin later

any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess file cannot help you with the links coming *out of* your WordPress plugin. You will need to change your WordPress plugin to generate the url in `/x/y` format (which will already be redirected to your index.php since you're using WordPress Permalinks) and then work out how to retrieve that information from within WordPress.